# Declaring ULONG_MAX in C

Tags: c, var, ulong

I have been doing a lot of research on `ULONG_MAX` and trying to find out how to declare it, but it doesn't seem to work. I using the header `#include <stdio.h>` and `#include <limits.h` to make `ULONG_MAX` work. There is nothing much about `ULONG_MAX` online, so that is making it difficult for me to use it. I feel like I am using `ULONG_MAX` wrong.

**Question**: How to declare `ULONG_MAX`

**Sample Code**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

main(){
  ULONG_MAX number;

  return 0;
}
```

**Error**:

```
gcc version 4.6.3

main.c:4:1: warning: return type defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
 main(){
 ^~~~
main.c: In function 'main':
main.c:5:13: error: expected ';' before 'number'
   ULONG_MAX number;
             ^~~~~~
main.c:6:3: error: 'num' undeclared (first use in this function)
   num = ULONG_MAX;
   ^~~
main.c:6:3: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in

exit status 1
```

The compiler I am using: [Repl.it](http://repl.it)

Comment: i think ULONG_MAX is macro or constant defined for the system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ULONG_MAX` is not a type, it's the maximum *value* allowed for an `unsigned long` type, typically defined as something like:

```
#define ULONG_MAX 0xFFFFFFFFUL
```

So, semantically, there is no difference between:

```
ULONG_MAX number;
```

and the clearly incorrect:

```
42 number;
```

In order to *use* the value, you would do something like:

```
unsigned long bigVal = ULONG_MAX;
```

Comment: is bigVal the name of my integer?

Comment: @Manav: yes, `bigVal` is the *name* of the variable, it's of *type* `unsigned long`, and its initial *value* is `ULONG_MAX`.

Comment: (assume 32-bit unsigned log) Must the **type** of the expression `ULONG_MAX` be some _unsigned_ type?  Are  `#define ULONG_MAX 0xFFFFFFFF`, `#define ULONG_MAX 4294967295` and `#define ULONG_MAX  4294967295u` OK?  (Or should I post a question?)